# Basic Authentication with WCF Web API Preview 6

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-security

I'm trying to use the new WCF Web API Preview 6 with Basic Authentication. But don't really know where to begin.

zanewill apparently had the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304367/how-to-use-basic-authentication-with-wcf-web-api
But the question is not a dup. I'm using this with mvc and don't really see how
[Wcf Basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220555/wcf-basic-authentication/8220615)
should apply?

I've tried out this:
http://cacheandquery.com/blog/2011/03/customizing-asp-net-mvc-basic-authentication/
But can't get it to work.
Should there not be an official solution from MS?

I have to note, that we are using our custom membership provider and that I basically just wanna pass an API token to the service. So the built in Windows Basic Authentification cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out a way myself. I've built my custom HttpOperationHandler and combined it with an Attribute, so I get a similar functionality as the MVC AuthorizeAttribute.

You can have a look at the solution here:
http://remy.supertext.ch/2012/02/basic-authentication-with-wcf-web-api-preview-6/

Comment: I have a new version for the MVC Web API:
http://remy.supertext.ch/2012/04/basic-http-authorization-for-web-api-in-mvc-4-beta/

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended approach is to implement custom message handler. See my blog post for an example that works with ASP.NET Web API RTM:

http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/